# Is there any software for testing cad model waterproofing and isolation?

Tags: cad, waterproofing

I have a cad model of a plastic box that is made of two parts. Two parts are connected with resin isolation. I want to test if my part is at least in theory ip86 water-resistant. So is there any software for testing cad model waterproofing and isolation?

Comment: well, yes sortof. But it really depends on the answer you want. Are you intereated only in wether the object is completely sealed then you need to model the resin in. (Which requires you to place the resin that way too). But this in it self does not help inany way as "some plastic" is way too inaccurate, you need to know what plastic and what manufacturing method and then what pressure conditions and loads.... So usually its more of a question that the simulation requiresyou to know too many things that you do not know.